# Api post call is not working in using Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-http

I am working in angular 4 using web api 2 my post call is not working doesn't hit api. The problem is that it doesn't even give me a single error. Here is my code

```
 registerUser() {
    this.confirmPasswordMessage = false;
    if (this.registerForm.valid) {
      this.confirmPasswordMessage = false;
         if (this._registerModel.Password.trim() !== this._registerModel.ConfirmPassword.trim()) {
             this.confirmPasswordMessage = true;
             this._progressBar.done();
             return false;
        }
        const _data = JSON.stringify(this._registerModel);
        this._apiService.postCall('Account/Register', _data).subscribe(resp => {
        }, error => () => {
          console.log(error); }, () => {
          });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Here is my api service code.

```
public postCall<T>(apiUrl: any, itemName: any): Observable<T> {
    const _options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
      }
    )};
      return this.http.post<T>(this.actionUrl + apiUrl, itemName, _options);
  }
```

Here is my json I am passing. When i run this json through postman it hit the api. But I don't why it is not hitting it from angular application.

```
"{"FirstName":"Kamran","LastName":"Khan","Email":"kamrankhan473@gmail.com","UserName":"kamrankhan","Password":"Kamran@786","ConfirmPassword":"Kamran@786"}"
```

There is nothing wrong with the api it is working fine I tested using postman.

Comment: If it doesn't hit api, as you claim (= no request seen in Network devtools either?), then check if the `registerUser`method gets called at all, if it does - is the form actually valid? (Btw, you also seem to redundantly reset the message this.confirmPasswordMessage)

Comment: 1. Unrelated, why are you converting the data to string using `JSON.stringify()` and also mention `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`? The data should be sent without the conversion: `this._apiService.postCall('Account/Register', this._registerModel)`.

Comment: i think you no need JSON.stringify your data for http.post() call

Comment: I have also try this not strinigify the model but still no reponse.

Comment: The apiUrl gives me this link, http://localhost:20863/

Comment: Form is valid and is working properly but no response from the post call :(

Comment: 2. You need to remove all occurences of the generic type variable `<T>` from the `postCall()`. You aren't using it in your call.

Comment: 3. Add a leading slash to the URL string. Try with `'/Account/Register'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple issues.

1. Remove the `return false` inside the `if` condition. It returns from the function before the HTTP request is made.
2. The `else` block is redundant. The function will return either way regardless of the `if` statement was true or not.
3. Remove the `JSON.stringify()`. You need to send the JSON, not a string.
4. Add a leading slash to the URL. Replace `'Account/Register'` with `'/Account/Register'`.
5. Issue in definition of error callback function. Here `error` is the parameter for the function. You can't define a function of form `error => () => {}`.
6. The generic type variable `<T>` in the service function is redundant. It isn't being used here.

Try the following

Component

```js
registerUser() {
  this.confirmPasswordMessage = false;
  if (this.registerForm.valid) {
    this.confirmPasswordMessage = false;
    if (this._registerModel.Password.trim() !== this._registerModel.ConfirmPassword.trim()) {
      this.confirmPasswordMessage = true;
      this._progressBar.done();
      // no `return false;` here
    }
    this._apiService.postCall('/Account/Register', this._registerModel).subscribe(
      resp => { console.log(resp); }, 
      error => { console.log(error); }, 
      () => { console.log('complete'); }
    );
  }
}
```

Service

```js
public postCall(apiUrl: any, itemName: any): Observable<any> {
  const _options = { 
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    }
  )};
  return this.http.post(this.actionUrl + apiUrl, itemName, _options);
}
```

If you're starting with Angular, I'd recommend you to go through the Angular [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) first. It introduces the basic concepts of Angular.